# Unable to cast object of type 'Obout.Grid.GridTemplate' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'. not resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, obout

I want to `disable gridview` row on button click which is inside the gridview. So for that I have written the below code.

```
protected void btnPayGenInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (strMode == "M")
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;
        row.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

But I am getting error as

> Unable to cast object of type 'Obout.Grid.GridTemplate' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

kindly let me know what is wrong here

**UPDATE**

Getting error at line `GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;`

**update 2**

Code for button click event.

```
protected void GetRowDataPay(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

    Hashtable dataItemPay = GridPayInfo.Rows[rowIndex].ToHashtable() as Hashtable;

    if (ObjPriCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        ObjPriCon.Open();
        OracleCommand cmdMkeyPay = new OracleCommand("select XXCUS.XXACL_LAND_PURC_INV_VIEW_MKEY.nextval from dual", ObjPriCon);
        string MkeyPay = Convert.ToString(cmdMkeyPay.ExecuteOracleScalar());

        OracleCommand cmdORGID = new OracleCommand("select XXCUS.XXACL_LAND_PURC_INV_VIEW_MKEY.nextval from dual", ObjPriCon);
        string ORG_IDKEY = CF.ExecuteScaler2("select ORGANIZATION_ID,ORGANIZATION_NAME from apps.xxacl_company_mst where ORGANIZATION_NAME = '" + txtCompName.Value + "'");

        string strExpQuery = "insert into XXCUS.XXACL_LAND_PURC_INVOICE_VIEW (MKEY,REF_PURCHASE_ID,REF_SR_NO, " +
                         "REF_PURHCASE_TYPE,ORG_ID,PROJECT_ID,TALUKA_ID,VILLAGE_ID,SURVEY_AREA_7_12,DOC_NO,INVOICE_ID,INVOICE_NUM,VENDOR_ID, " +
                         "VENDOR_NAME,INVOICE_AMT,BATCH_ID,BATCH_NAME,EXP_ID,EXP_TYPE,REMARKS,CREATED_BY, " +
                         "CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY, EXP_ORG_ID, EXP_ORG_NAME) values (" + MkeyPay + "," + StrMkey + "," +
                         "" + dataItemPay["SR_NO"] + ", '" + dataItemPay["ATTRIBUTE1"] + "'," + ORG_IDKEY + "," + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "," +
                         "" + ddlTaluka.SelectedValue + "," + ddlVillage.SelectedValue + ", '" + txt712.Text + "', '" + txtdocno.Value + "'," + "NULL" + "," + "NULL" + "," +
                         "" + dataItemPay["ORACLE_VENDOR_ID"] + ", '" + dataItemPay["ORACLE_VEND_NAME"] + "', " + dataItemPay["PAID_AMT"] + "," + dataItemPay["BATCH_ID"] + "," +
                         "'" + dataItemPay["BATCH_NAME"] + "', " + dataItemPay["EXP_ID"] + ", '" + dataItemPay["EXP_TYPE"] + "', '" + dataItemPay["REMARKS"] + "', " +
                         "" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + ", sysdate, sysdate, " +
                         "'" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "', " + "NULL" + "," + "NULL" + ")";
        OracleCommand cmdQuery = new OracleCommand(strExpQuery, ObjPriCon);
        cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ObjPriCon.Close();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Success", "alert('Payment Invoice inserted into table successfully');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which row u want to disable . Yiu need to get the selected rows which u want to disable and pass it to code . then you can disable that row .

Comment: @YashveerSingh: Yes, I want to disable the row for which the button is clicked.

Comment: OK so you must have an selected row event which will be fired when you select that record  on that event you can do this stuff .

Comment: I will update the event code in my question. Do let me know how to get selected row and disable it.

Comment: ok I will try my best

Comment: updated the question @YashveerSingh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136244/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-nad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the rowIndex value to get the gridviewrow and then disable it something like this

```
if (GridPayInfo.Rows[rowIndex] != null) 
{ 
  GridPayInfo.Rows[rowIndex].Enabled = false; 
}
```

Comment: protected void btnPayGenInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (GridPayInfo.Rows[rowIndex] != null) 
{ 
    if (strMode == "M")
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow.Rows[rowIndex].Enabled = false; 
    }
}

}

Comment: thanks Yashveer, this one is working perfectly fine..!! Need to know how to disable the delete part.

Comment: I have many other questions, will post later on and let you know. thanks for now.. have a good day

Comment: Hi @nad no issues please let me know the question I will try my best to answer

Comment: @nad yes please tell me

Comment: come on chat.. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136244/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-nad

Comment: hi, are u their, if possible come on chat.